# how to dynamically rewrite the url?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

**original url** 
http://wwww.mydomain.com/image.php?id=13&cat=4&type=3$date=2011-03-14

i want to modify this **dynamic url** to something like this

http://www.mydomain.com/imageid/imagetitle (no php/html extension at the end )

plz if someone could help me in this , i have tried several online generators but my modification is little different.

I don't know how to write mods .

Comment: What is the image title in original url ?

Comment: @melih altintas there is no parameter for imagetitle in original url , will i have to include image title parameter in original url to mod rewrite ? if that so then i edit my original url.

Answer (score 0):

well, to get it you could need a page that redirects you to another location.
in the head section of your html page you have to specify a meta tag like it:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; http://www.mydomain.com/imageid/imagetitle" />
```

when you land on that page, it counts to seconds you specified in the first argument of content (in this case 0 seconds) and opens the new page passed as the second parameter.

a easy thing you could do to avoid extensions to be visible on the address bar of your browser is to create a folder in your web server (in your case "imagetitle") and put inside it an index page for example "index.html" which is the page loaded by default when a user aims to that link

Comment: its not auto redirect after xx seconds , when user clicks on the link then it should redirect from original to new.

Comment: are you talking about <a> tag with "href" property?